# Embedding python in a c program with all dependencies included

Tags: python, c

I am writing a c application that will let me embed python modules in it. The python modules are responsible for initiating remote procedure calls to python code on remote machine through rpyc library. My python modules will be located in the same place where the application will run from. I am assuming that my c application will run on a machine that does not have the needed python libraries e.g rpyc. I wanted to know if there is a way I can bundle all the dependencies together with my modules when I ship the code for distribution.

I have used cython to compile the python module to .pyd but still this needs the required python libraries installed.

My c code;

```
int main(){
    int argc = 2;
    wchar_t* argv[] = { (wchar_t *)"mypythonmodule", (wchar_t *)"-h", NULL };
    const char *module = argv[0];
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(module);
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc);
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            pValue = PyUnicode_FromString(argv[i]);
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
        }
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "parse_args");
        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        //Py_DECREF(pValue);
        Py_Finalize();
    }
}
```